# Magento2 - Admin panel loader keep loading don't stop

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, loading

I installed Magento on localhost and login in admin panel but admin panel loader keeps loading. Admin panel did not load properly.

I have attached the screen shot here.

[image]

Comment: Check in console log for any error.

Comment: run the content deploy command again and check the logs for any JS error

Answer (score 1):

Run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` from Magento root directory